# Using the new browser bundle with IRC

Tags: windows, vidalia, socks

I am a Windows user. And in the past I used a solution to connect to IRC which involved:

IRC Client ---> FreeCap ---> Tor

Now I understand XChat supports SOCK5 proxy connection, which is what I believe tor was providing at the time. Now, I tend to banned frequently on IRC and so I need to receive a new identity regularly. In the past there was a tray application for Windows called vidalia, which had a "get new identity" button. However this application seems to have vanished and is replaced with the tor browser bundle. So, is it still possible to connect threw TOR with SOC5, and is there a way to get new identities... I'm sorry for not understanding, but most of the material I have found is only useful for Debian, not Windows.

Comment: What is your question? At the moment I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: You can still use SOCKS5 via the Tor Browser, it listens on port 9150. https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#TBBSocksPort You can also use Vidalia to get a new identity as described here: https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#WhereDidVidaliaGo Some IRC networks require registered clients with Tor, you can use HexChat (http://hexchat.github.io/) which supports SASL out of the box.

Comment: That makes seance, So is it the case that I need to first run "tor firefox" than Vidalia than an application that uses the proxy?

Comment: I still seem to be getting an error with that setup, it says "[Warning] Rejecting SOCKS request for anonymous connection to private address [scrubbed]." Should I be using a different hostname than 127.0.0.1?